# Getting a "money converter" Android app to convert one currency to another based on user input

Tags: java, android, json, xml, android-studio

So here are my instructions:

> Retrieve current currency conversion rates from :
>
> ```
>  http://api.fixer.io
> ```
>
> For example, to convert US dollars to British pounds you call:
>
> ```
>  http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD&symbols=GBP
> ```
>
> 2- Provide two spinners with 5 currencies of your choosing.
>
> 3 - use async calls for the conversion lookups, they shouldn't block
>   the UI thread.

Now I've gotten as far as pulling values from the JSON API and getting it to successfully display the conversion rate of 1 USD to 1 GBP (this was done by hard coding in USD and GBP to pull from the JSON API. But now I'm struggling trying to get the hard coded currencies to instead be pulled from a pair of spinners containing 5 different currencies. Additionally I'm struggling to get the rate to multiply by a user specified amount (for example if the rate is 0.69 and the user wants to convert 10USD to GBP the app should report that the converted amount is 6.90GBP) but at present all I am getting is "Operator * cannot be applied to double"
At present the app crashes at launch and my first priority is getting it to run and convert 1 monetary unit to an equivalent amount of another monetary unit.

**This is my FetchConversionRateTask.java file**

*And also where Android Studio is throwing the error*

```
package edu.ggc.tkeating.currencyconverter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by T3P0 on 6/9/2016.
 */

//http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD&symbols=GBP
public class FetchConversionRateTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Double> {

    private HttpURLConnection conn;
    private TextView tv;
    private Context context;
    private EditText amount;
    private TextView conversionTV;

    public FetchConversionRateTask(Context _context, TextView _tv, EditText _amount){
        this.tv = _tv;
        this.context = _context;
        this.amount = _amount;
    }

    private final static String TAG = "CurrencyConverter";




    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        MediaPlayer tingMP = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.ting);
        tingMP.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... currencies){
        String from = currencies[0];
        String to = currencies[1];
        double rate = 0.0d;
        double conversion = 0.0d;


        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://api.fixer.io/latest?base="+ from +
                    "&symbols="+ to);
            conn =  (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            Scanner scanner = null;
            scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream()));


            String rslt ="";
            while (scanner.hasNext()) rslt += scanner.nextLine();
            Log.i(TAG, rslt);

            // {"base":"USD","date":"2016-06-09","rates":{"GBP":0.69151}}
            rate = new JSONObject(rslt).getJSONObject("rates").getDouble(to);
            conversion = new JSONObject(rslt).getJSONObject("conversion").getDouble(String.valueOf(amount));



            scanner.close();
            return conversion;

        } catch (IOException | JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rate;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Double rate){
        super.onPostExecute(rate);
        MediaPlayer tingMP = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.ting);
        tingMP.start();
        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
        String msg = "rate=" + format.format(rate);
        Log.i(TAG, msg);
        tv.setText(msg);


    }
}
```

**This is my MainActivity.java**

```
package edu.ggc.tkeating.currencyconverter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView result;
    private EditText amount;
    private String fromCurr;
    private String toCurr;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConvert);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
        amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);
        Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerFrom);
        fromCurr = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerTo);
        toCurr = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.currency_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new FetchConversionRateTask(getApplicationContext(), result,
                        amount).execute(fromCurr, toCurr);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="edu.ggc.tkeating.currencyconverter.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="edu.ggc.tkeating.currencyconverter">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="edu.ggc.tkeating.currencyconverter.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Convert"
        android:id="@+id/btnConvert"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Result"
        android:id="@+id/tvResult"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnConvert"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnConvert"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="79dp"
        android:hint="How much do you want to convert?"/>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerTo"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnConvert"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvResult"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvResult"/>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerFrom"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnConvert"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnConvert"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnConvert"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Result"
        android:id="@+id/conversionTV"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvResult"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I feel like i'm missing something incredibly simple and obvious and I'm hoping fresh eyes (and more experienced programmers) will be able to figure this code out. Thank you in advanced

Comment: What line is it on?

Comment: Post the stacktrace please